# Is there a way to remove or change the settings of the Wifi Direct WPS?

Tags: android, security, wifi-direct, wifi

In Wifi Alliance technical specification, they suggest the usage of WPS which was followed by android in order to be compliant with the specification.
But i would like to know if there is a way to modify this behavior so that two devices can connect automatically without any wps setting types (Pin, NFC or PBC)?
Is there a way to modify the android implementation so that they can still connect automatically?